# Regex to extract items from list

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with specific format and I'd like to extract its data into python array. What is the regEX string format for this?

**The string**

`417,364.4265,2535.2258,16.7616,143.5451,0,0 ; Leviathan`

**Array**

`arr = ['417', '364.4265', '2535.2258', '16.7616', '143.5451', '0', '0', 'Leviathan']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with the to split on multiple separators:

```
import re
s  ='417,364.4265,2535.2258,16.7616,143.5451,0,0 ; Leviathan'

re.split(r' *[,;] *',s)
# ['417', '364.4265', '2535.2258', '16.7616', '143.5451', '0', '0', 'Leviathan']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
import re

string = "417,364.4265,2535.2258,16.7616,143.5451,0,0 ; Leviathan"
rx = re.compile(r'([^,;\s]+)')
output = rx.findall(string)
print(output)
```

Which yields

```
['417', '364.4265', '2535.2258', '16.7616', '143.5451', '0', '0', 'Leviathan']
```

Answer (score 0):

if U can add space between the numbers U can use the split method

```
s=417 364.4265 2535.2258 16.7616 143.5451 0 0 Leviathan
s=s.split()
```

output:

```
['417','364.4265','2535.2258','16.7616','143.5451','0','0','Leviathan']
```

it's easier and U don' need to put extra libraries

Comment: Of course. But if the string was in another format (or could be changed therein), the question would be rather pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: at a certain point, yes, but if it is to separate in a string, the split () method will always separate through spaces, but if they are commas to separate, I do not know to what extent the split () method can be used.